# KeePassXC have not access to base on my Ubuntu desktop

Tags: keepassx

Why i cant get access to my base on second drive?

[image]

Comment: Did you install this with the snap?

Comment: How is your second drive mounted does it have an entry in fstab?  Please append your question with the output of `ls -ld /media/veter`

Comment: veter@Dell:~$ ls -ld /media/veter
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 дек  3 16:43 /media/veter

Comment: I install it using default Ubuntu software center.